Jacobian of the solution to the Lyapunov equation (continuous time)
Let $\mathbf{A}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ be a real, invertible, symmetric matrix.
Let $\mathbf{Q}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ be a real, invertible matrix.
Let $\mathbf{X}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ be the solution to the Lyapunov equation in continuous time:
\begin{align*}
   \mathbf{X} \ = \ \int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t}\, dt
\end{align*}
I am trying to take the derivative of a function of $\mathbf{X}$ with respect to some parameters $\mathbf{H}$, where values in $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ are functions of $\mathbf{H}$. It is not clear to me how to proceed. I know I can write the derivative of the function via the product of Jacobians, but I don't know how to get past this part involving the Lyapunov solution.
I assume that I would need the Jacobians of $\mathbf{X}$ with respect to both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, i.e. in the forms
$\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times N^2}$ and $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{Q})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times N^2}$.
Even if I had these quantities, I'm not sure how I would proceed. Would the differential of $\mathbf{X}$ be given by:
\begin{align*}
   d \mathbf{X} \ = \ \int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{d \mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{d \mathbf{A}t}\, dt + \int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ d \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t}\, dt
\end{align*}
and I could proceed from there?

I'm wondering if I should not directly invoke the solution to the Lyapunov equation, but instead invoke the equation itself: $\mathbf{A}$ $\mathbf{X}$ $+$ $\mathbf{X}$ $\mathbf{A}$ $=$ $-\mathbf{Q}$ , and take the differentials with respect to this equation. E.g., something like $-d \mathbf{Q}$ $=$ ($d \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}$ $+$ $\mathbf{A} d \mathbf{X}$) + ($d \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}$ $+$ $\mathbf{X} d \mathbf{A}$), if that is correct.

Using the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)= x(t)+y(t)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{df(x,y)}{dt}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}
\end{align*}
Using this to help us realign ourselves, we get:
\begin{align*}
  d \mathbf{X} \ = \ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}} \ \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t}\, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{A}  +\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{Q}} \ \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \  \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t}\, dt \right ) \ d \mathbf{Q}
\end{align*}
Knowing nothing about your problem this is where I would stop. However, if your problem satisfies Leibniz's Integral Rule we can reduce this to:
\begin{align*}
    d \mathbf{X} \ = \  \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}} \ \left (\mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \right ) \, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{A}  +\ \  \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{Q}} \ \left (\mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \right ) \, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{Q}
\end{align*}
Which we can simplify to:
\begin{align*}
   d \mathbf{X} \ = \  \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \  \ \left ( \ \frac{\partial \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ + \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \frac{\partial \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} \ \right ) \, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{A}  +\ \  \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{I} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \  \, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{Q}
\end{align*}
Which finally resolves to:
\begin{align*}
   d \mathbf{X} \ = \ 2 \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \ t \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \ \mathbf{Q} \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} \, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{A}  +\ \  \left ( \int_{0}^\infty \ \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathbf{A}t}  \, dt \right ) \   d \mathbf{Q}
\end{align*}
Edit: for clarification, here I am using $d\mathbf{X}$ as shorthand for $\frac{d\mathbf{X}}{d\mathbf{H}}$. Additionally, I forgot to transfer in integrating variable t and have edited my answer to reflect this.

Thank you avringo, I will look into whether the Lyapunov solution satisfies Leibniz's integral rule. This seems like a place for me to start.

The differential computation seems wrong. For example, it should be $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{At}dQe^{At} ,dt$ instead of $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{2At},dt,dQ$. I believe the first term is also wrong.

Mason, when you say it should be $\int_{0}^\infty \ \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} d \mathbf{Q} \mathrm{e}^{\mathbf{A}t} , dt$ instead of $\int_{0}^\infty \ \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathbf{A}t}  , dt d \mathbf{Q}$, are you assuming that the problem satisfies Leibniz's integral rule (as in avringo's answer)? Or more generally, is there a particular line in avringo's answer that you disagree with?

@Tychus Yes I assume that we can differentiate under the integral, which is most often the case, but should be checked at some point. See my answer for details.

I believe @Mason is correct. see this post as the problem is more complicated than I assumed.

We give two approaches to the computation of $dX (H)$, where $X : \mathbb{R}^p
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$.
First approach: We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  X (H) & = & \int_0^{\infty} e^{At} Qe^{At} dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
By differentiating under the integral sign, which can be justified using
dominated convergence or some other method and depends on the particulars of
$A (H)$ and $Q (H)$ and their derivatives, we have the differential of $X$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  dX (H) & = & \int_0^{\infty} d (e^{At} Qe^{At}) dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  d (e^{At} Qe^{At}) & = & d (e^{At}) Qe^{At} + e^{At} dQe^{At} + e^{At} Qd
  (e^{At}) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
  dX (H) & = & \int_0^{\infty} (d (e^{At}) Qe^{At} + e^{At} dQe^{At} + e^{At}
  Qd (e^{At})) dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
The differential of $d (e^{tA})$ in terms of $dA$ is given as a series, see
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885885710172. I
don't think there are any more simplifications that can be done here.
Second approach: We have $AX + XA = - Q$, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
  - dQ & = & (dA) X + AdX + (dX) A + X (dA) .
\end{eqnarray*}
I don't think this can be simplified further.
